# What should authenticateToken() return or throw? Symfony 2.4

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I'm just creating a new Symfony2 project based on version 2.4.

Working with http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-customize-the-security-features-with-ease I created a UserProvider and Authenticator.

According to provided examples `authenticateToken()` should return proper token or `throw new AuthenticationException('message')`. In first case when User can be authenticated - everything works fine but when an Exception is thrown - server is not giving 401 or 403 with just regular auth error but is giving 500 with `A Token was not found in the SecurityContext!` I think it is a new implementation bug, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

OK, documentation is quite blind for some cases. It is all about entry_point or setting FailureListener.

What you need to remember:

1. Must define `access_control` in your `security.yml`
2. Must provide service implementing `AuthenticationEntryPointInterface` as a `entry_point`
   /or/
3. Must implement `AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface` in your `Authenticator` in order to response your own Exceptions.

In my case - solution #3 was proper one.